# Grpc async bidirectional client using c++

Tags: asynchronous, client, grpc, bidirectional, bidi

I am using bidirectional grpc between my client and server. I would like to implement async bidi on both client and server i.e., client opens a stream and starts sending arbitrary messages to server, while another thread continues receiving server responses. This example below demonstrates the server side async bidi https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/grpc-io/DuBDpK96B14. 
Has anyone tried async bidi on client side?

Answer (score -2):

There's a codelab for it with both client and server at https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/async/helloasync-cpp/

Async client

To use an asynchronous client to call a remote method, you first create a channel and stub, just as you do in a synchronous client. Once you have your stub, you do the following to make an asynchronous call:

Initiate the RPC and create a handle for it. Bind the RPC to a CompletionQueue.

```
    CompletionQueue cq;
    std::unique_ptr<ClientAsyncResponseReader<HelloReply> > rpc(
        stub_->AsyncSayHello(&context, request, &cq));
```

Ask for the reply and final status, with a unique tag

```
    Status status;
    rpc->Finish(&reply, &status, (void*)1);
```

Wait for the completion queue to return the next tag. The reply and status are ready once the tag passed into the corresponding Finish() call is returned.

```
    void* got_tag;
    bool ok = false;
    cq.Next(&got_tag, &ok);
    if (ok && got_tag == (void*)1) {
      // check reply and status
    }
```

You can see the complete client example in [greeter_async_client.cc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.25.0/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_client.cc).

Comment: Seems to just be a copy from the tutorial web site...